# How to make this thread-safe

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, thread-safety, sessionfactory

I have the following SessionFactory for Fluent NHibernate.

I am getting an error of

> An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.

with an InnerException of

> An item with the same key has already been added.

This problem is only happening occasionally and my application works fine most of the time.

Based on [NHibernate: System.Argument Exception : An item with the same key has already been added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855149/nhibernate-system-argument-exception-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-bee) I'm guessing my class is not thread-safe which would explain the intermittent nature of this error.

```
using System;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cache;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using WSS.Data.Domain;

namespace WSS.Data {
    public static class SessionFactory {
        private static ISessionFactory _factory = null;
        private static ISessionFactory GetFactory() {
            if (_factory == null) {
                NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config;
                config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
                config.Configure();
                if (config == null) {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("NHibernate configuration is null.");
                }


                config.AddAssembly("WSS.Data");
                _factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
                if (_factory == null) {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Call to Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
                }
            }
            return _factory;

        }

        private static ISessionFactory GetFluentFactory() {
            if(_factory == null) {
                _factory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2000
                        .ConnectionString(c => c
                            .Is(ConnectionStrings.Auto))
                        .Cache(c => c
                            .UseQueryCache()
                            .ProviderClass())
                        .ShowSql())
                    .Mappings(m => m
                        .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf())
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _factory;
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession() {
            ISession session;
            session = GetFluentFactory().OpenSession();
            if (session == null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Call to factory.OpenSession() returned null.");
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach is to create a mutex (probably in your public method) that only allows single access.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Not tested as compiling, but something like:

```
    private static Mutex _sessionMutex = new Mutex();

    public static ISession OpenSession() {
        ISession session;

        _sessionMutex.WaitOne();

        session = GetFluentFactory().OpenSession();
        if (session == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Call to factory.OpenSession() returned null.");
        }

        _sessionMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        return session;
    }
```

Comment: @IamStalker: What doesn't work? Post a new question with code that demonstrates the problem. The other approach that can work is to use "lock," but that only works for a single process (and its threads) rather than system-wide.