# An item with the same key has already been added. Is the following way Correct?

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sessionfactory

I know this is a duplicate post but my context is different.
I went through the solution for this problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5353282/1518640).
And I some how changed as follows:

```
    private static Mutex _sessionMutex = new Mutex();
    public void OpenMySessionFactory(string conStr)
        {
            try
            {
                _sessionMutex.WaitOne();
                config = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(conStr))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
                .BuildConfiguration();
                sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
                _sessionMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Is there any impact if I implement as above?

Reason behind error :

> An item with the same key has already been added

is occuring when I double click on any button that has to do something with data access using Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if an exception does occur, you will never unlock the mutex (the control will jump to the `catch` block and skip the unlocking). Use a `finally` block to do this:

```
public void OpenMySessionFactory(string conStr)
{
    _sessionMutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        config = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(conStr))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
        .BuildConfiguration();
        sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        _sessionMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```